# How to Translate Mvc4.Paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paging

I have Included Mvc4.Paging package on my site, now i need to translate words like:

> Showing items 51 through 53 of 53.

or

> Page 1 of 5

here is code for paging:

```
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page,
searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"],
search = Request.QueryString["search"]
} ),

    new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true }
)
```

How can i translate this to show in View on my MVC Project?

Comment: [MvcPaging](https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging)  doesn't have a PagedListPager. The page though shows a lot of options to customize the text labels. What package are you talking about ?

Comment: Are you talking about [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList) perhaps? That too offers a lot of customization options

Comment: I installed nuget Mvc4.Paging,  using PagedList; using PagedList.Mvc;

Answer (score 1):

I founded answer on this [Link:](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs/) about formatting the Pager

Or code looked like this:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {
    page,
    searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"],
    search = Request.QueryString["search"]
} ),

    new PagedListRenderOptions() {
        LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Прва",
        LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Претходна",
        LinkToNextPageFormat = "Следна >",
        LinkToLastPageFormat = "&Uacute;Последна >>",
        Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
        DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true,
        PageCountAndCurrentLocationFormat = "Страна {0} од {1}.",
        DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
        ItemSliceAndTotalFormat = "Прикажувам од {0} до {1} од вкупно {2}." }
)
```